# animation package cannot find ImageMagick with convert = "convert"

Tags: r, animation, imagemagick

I have run animations in the past up to 2 weeks ago on Windows 7, R 3.0.1.  Today I loaded R 3.0.2 and needed to download the animations package to run make an animation.  After doing so when I try to run the animation ([here is a script](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503/wordpress/Just_R.txt)) I get the following error:

```
> saveGIF(FUN2(), interval = 0.1, outdir = "images/animate")
I cannot find ImageMagick with convert = "convert"
NULL
Warning messages:
1: running command 'convert --version' had status 4 
2: In im.convert(img.files, output = movie.name, convert = convert,  :
  ImageMagick not installed yet!
```

I have ImageMagick installed and on the path as demonstrated in the video I made of the problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvpawqLyCZY&feature=youtu.be

I can run `convert --version` in the Windows command line and get the following:

```
C:\Users\trinker>convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.6-8 2013-08-04 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lzma openexr pa
ngo png ps tiff webp x xml zlib
```

Yet running `system("convert --version")` in R yields:

```
Invalid drive specification.
Warning message:
running command 'convert --version' had status 4
```

What am I doing wrong or might I alter to make the animation package (and R) see ImageMagick?

Here is additional information for the problem (in the R command line I get):

```
> system("convert -version")
Invalid drive specification.
Warning message:
running command 'convert -version' had status 4 

> shell("convert --version")
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-9 Q16 x64 2013-11-28 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr pangocairo png ps tiff webp xml zlib
```

Comment: I think `cmd.fun = shell` may allow things to work.  If it does I am still wondering what changed.  I'll report back.

Comment: I think we have fixed this problem in the development version using `shell` as the default value under Windows: https://github.com/yihui/animation/blob/master/R/im.convert.R#L78 Would you mind testing the devel version on Github? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue with the {rgl} `movie3d()` function.  In that case you can explicitly pass a convert string to be executed, and so can 'tell' R where to find the right `convert.exe`:

`imconvertstring<-"\"c:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16\\convert.exe\" -delay 1x%d %s*.png %s.%s"`

`movie3d(spin3d(),duration=10,convert=imconvertstring)`

You can do the same with the {animation} package using `ani.options()` to specify the exact location to `convert.exe` needed.  See the help entry for `im.convert()` in the {animation} package.

Comment: NOTE: version ImageMagick-7.0.3-4.x86_64.rpm (and possibly some earlier versions) do not install convert.exe by default; make sure to check the option box during installation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many people know this.

There is already a program called convert in newer versions of windows that does something with filesystems.  After installing Imagemagick I renamed the IM convert and used that to make system calls.  I haven't used the animation package yet so I can't speak to the best way to solve this particular problem.

Comment: Are you referring to `convert.exe` which changes FAT to NTFS or the other way around?  There's a different "convert" command which is part of ImageMagick (see for example `bash man convert`)

Comment: That is right.  I've had problems with that filesystem convert being the default when I was trying to use the IM convert. Another suggestion instead of renaming the IM convert would be to give the full file path.  Since this is in the animation package I'm not familiar if that is how it is used and the package might be using the filesystem convert accidentally.